# Parse Seamless Login

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have created an app using parse with **Swift** , when a user opens the app (not from the background) the login screen shows for a split second before moving to the main view. I wan't it to go straight to the main screen if the user is logged in.

I have tried putting the following code nearly everywhere.

```
if PFUser.currentUser() != nil {

}
```

I tried NSUserDefaults to check if the user is logged in, in the app delegate didFinishLaunching, couldn't get it to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated , thanks.

Comment: can you post your storyboard or the part where you show the login screen that I can see how you implemented the loginscreen logic?

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the check into your "**AppDelegate.swift**" file.

Then depending on if the user is logged in or not load the MAIN viewcontroller or the LOGIN viewcontroller.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool  {

       // Other stuff you need to setup the app...

        if PFUser.currentUser() == nil
       {
           //Load the Login ViewController
       }
       else 
       {
           //Load the Main ViewController
       }
       return true
 }
```